# How to make an eye glare effect in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop-effects, photo-editing

How would I go about recreating this effect in Photoshop? The picture itself reminds me of actual pictures I have seen from photobooths, and the glare of his eyes seems realistic: it's brightest when he looks directly into the camera and is slightly dimmed when he looks away from it. How could I achieve this effect in Photoshop? Thanks in advance. [image: this] [image: and this]

Comment: Hi inkd, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this effect in Photoshop.

Just go to "Filter > Render > Lens Flare" .   Once there just select the point where you want the lens to come from, in this case the eyes of the subject.   You'll have to go 1 eye at the time, so select the first eye then maybe you want to  select the option of "35mm Prime" (or any other that may adapt to the picture). Most likely the brightness should be 150% (but that could change depending on the size of your picture).

Do the same for the other eye.

Once you're done,  pass the "Burn Tool" around (from the eyes to where the glares reach).   This will give some details back to the picture still keeping the glares.

This should give you this effect.

Answer (score 1):

Another choice you may follow is to look for the direction in this manner.

Using the new layer, you draw two white circles across the eyes.

[image]

Go to **Layer Style** and Follow the steps (I mentioned by 1,2,3)

[image]

Result. (Hoping that you want it)

[image]